# Generating $\pi$-system for $\mathbb{Z}_+$

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

As we know from the definition a $\pi$-system is a collection where the intersection of two sets is again in that collection. In fact we can use $\pi$-systems to generate $\sigma$-algebra's. We know that a $\pi$-system generates a $\sigma$-algebra if the minimum $\sigma$-algebra containing the $\pi$-system is in fact the $\sigma$-algebra we want to generate.

I'm curious to what the "simplest" $\pi$-system is that generates the power set of non-negative integers $\mathbb{Z}_+$. I think the $\pi$-system should look something like
$$ \mathcal{I}=\left\{\{0,\ldots,n\},n\in\mathbb{Z}_+\right\}.$$
Then this is in fact a $\pi$-system but I don't know how to make it rigurous that it generates the power set of non-negative integers ($\sigma(\mathcal{I})=2^{\mathbb{Z}_+})$ and that it is in fact the "simplest" one.

For a more advanced question I want to refer to an unanswered one [$\pi$-systems for counting processes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1148533/generating-pi-system-for-counting-process). Thanks for any help.

Comment: You're 27 days early.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that for $n\geqslant 1$,  $\{ n\}=\{0,\dots,n\}\setminus\{0,\dots,n-1\}$, which is an element of the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal I$. We thus deduce that $\{0\}\in\sigma(\mathcal I)$.

We have shown that $\{n\} \in\sigma(\mathcal I)$ for each $n\in\mathbb Z_+$. Since each element of the power set of $\mathbb Z_+$ is a countable union of sets of the form $\{n\}$, $n\in\mathbb Z_+$, we showed that $\sigma(\mathcal I)=2^{\mathbb Z_+}  $.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Maybe this isn't the appropriate place but how could this $\pi$-system be extended to $\left(2^{\mathbb{Z}_+}\right)^{[0,\infty )}$? (refering to stochastic processes)